# Download pictures from amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to display the image from my amazon s3 buckets to web browser. But the result gave me an error **"The specified key doesnt exist"**. The file is exist inside buckets.

Here is my codes

```
public class TempActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView ivTemp;
    String key;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temporary);

        ivTemp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTemporary);

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.amazonAccessKeyID,
                Constants.amazonSecretAccessKey));

        key = "HJiDw6GkuS7gl82N4lCw.jpg";

        ResponseHeaderOverrides overrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
        overrides.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(Constants.amazonS3BucketName,key);
        urlRequest.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000));
        urlRequest.setResponseHeaders(overrides);
        URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.toURI().toString())));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

I've tried to do like:

1. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/Android/3002109349624271
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html
3. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest

What I want to do is I want to download images from my bucket on AWS.
Please advise.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This either means the key does not exist... or at least does not exist where you are looking.

Have you tried with a key that has a simpler name just to verify?
Are you sure the object in S3 has the .jpg extension?
Are you using versioning?
What if you don't set the response header override?
What if you set the region explicitly to the region the object is in?